# change this date format to work with new date()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a date returned from an API in the format:

```
var date = result.posted //gives 2014-03-29 02:07:26
```

when I run

```
new date(date)
```

on desktop it works fine
but on mobile, I get the error 'invalid date'

how can I make this work across the board - I want to compare it to the current time ( var cur_time = new date() )

Comment: Chop it using `split` or regex, or use a parsing library like [moment](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), it is very easy to compare date. In your case:

```
moment("2014-03-29 02:07:26", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").fromNow();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

`var date = new Date(Date.parse(parseInt(result.posted)))`

it will give date object like below

`Date {Wed Jan 01 2014 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}`

Comment: I don't know how did you get that from the sample given by the user. parseInt will return the numbers, which in this case is 2014.